# How to modify and display items in collection individually

Tags: meteor

I have a collection named Sites like this:

{ site: "a", price: 100, currency: USD }
{ site: "b", price: 70, currency: EUR }
{ site: "c", price: 300, currency: CNY }

In my template I have:

```
{{#each sites}}
{{site}}
{price}}
{{/each}}
```

My helper does this:

Template.prices.sites = function()
{
    return Sites.find();
};

The user is given a select option and I want to be able to show prices in a single currency according to the selection.

So If the user selects EUR, the price of the item: { site: "a", price: 100, currency: USD } will be displayed as price * eur_usd_exchange_rate

I can do this by creating individual template variables for each item and creating a different helper for each.

But I want to be able to use a single helper. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a `site` template like so:

```
<template name="prices">
  {{#each sites}}
    {{> site}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="site">
  {{site}}
  {{price}}
</template>
```

This gives you access to `this.price` and `this.currency` in the helper:

```
Template.site.helpers({
  price: function() {
    var selectedCurrency = Session.get('currency');
    return this.price * exchangeRate(selectedCurrency, this.currency);
  }
});
```

This assumes the selected currency is stored in the `currency` session variable. Then all you have to do is implement the `exchangeRate` function and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I need a better understanding of this argument though.

Comment: Inside of each iteration of `{{#each sites}}`, the context is a `site`. That context gets passed to each instance of the site template, so the template handlers have access to the site's data. If you walk through the [templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#templates) intro from the docs, and the [leaderboard example](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard), this may become more clear.

Comment: Thanks again. I've been trying to find a solution to another problem now. I have a sort by selection and on the helper I do "return Sites.find({}, {sort: {selected_sort_option: -1}});" but if I can't figure out how to sort the sites for price using their modified values. I should probably ask another question about it right?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yeah I'd ask another question. That way the code can be properly formatted.